What is the total capacitance on the VBUS line in this case?
I am working on a PCB that is supposed to be powered either by an USB Type-C or by a 3 cell LiPo battery, so in this scope I decided to use the TPS2121 power mux. The problem is I don't understand how this IC makes the connections, so I don't know if either C14, C27 or C15 are connected to the VBUS line. My only concerns are not to pass the maximum capacitance of 10uF allowed on the VBUS line. I would be grateful if somebody could help me!


If your 5 V bus is 0 V and USB is connected, is there any path within U11 from IN1 to IN2, for example via body diode? I would assume no, but devil's in the details.

It's been a long time since I've used KiCAD but I think they have SPICE tools. Couldn't you do an RC step response, assuming that all of the components have SPICE parameters?

@winny that is what I am trying to figure out, but I don't really know how.

@Colin I've never done that, but if I can't find my answer in other way I will try.

Seems no since they have a series N+P MOSFET pair.
